# PHP Fatal error: method_exists(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, queue

The problem is that I have two Laravel projects working on Laravel `5.1` and `5.3` and sharing common database. Both projects are placed on different subdomains up and running. 
Now while using `queue` driver as `database` for both projects I am using `5.3` demon to run on `5.1` queued jobs I am getting following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  method_exists(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "App\Jobs\StoreAppliedjob" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition  in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/admin-badiyajobs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php on line 83

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
```

The `5.1` queue is working fine when run with queue listener on `5.1` . Note that I can't use separate `cron` on both projects to process queue as that will mess up everything. Please suggest what should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

The queue serializes the Job before sending it to the queue and unserializes it when it's handled. You'll need the `App\Jobs\StoreAppliedjob` on the location where it's being handled.

Comment: Can you give an example or reference how it is done. I never found any need of doing so till date.

Comment: Well, from what I read you have 2 projects and your 5.3 project handles jobs from the 5.1 project. On itself that should not pose a real issue, the job interface and serialization is more or less identical. But the `App\Jobs\StoreAppliedjob` you push to the queue from the 5.1 project should also exist in the 5.3 project with the same namespace, otherwise the queue handler unserialize can not process it.

Comment: One thing though, I don't know how much 'other' code is required to handle the job. Usually related models, repos, etc exist in the codebase from which you push the job. Duplicating code from 1 project to the other for the sake of handling it, because it just happens to have running queue workers, is not a good solution.

Comment: Actually I checked both versions in terms of how they handle jobs. There are lots of difference .. So I did it using `Event` instead.

Comment: As long as you want to handle it in the same request cycle, doing so with events is an option yes. But some code should be handled async :)